# CSS :hover works but :active does not

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm preparing a WordPress theme and can't figure why `:active` in my CSS doesn't work while `:hover` is working fine.

HTML:

```
(...)
<div id="mainMenu">
  <div id="mm_links">
     <a id="mm_1" href="index.php/about-icar/">About ICAR</a><br/>
     <a id="mm_2" href="">News</a><br/>
     <a id="mm_3" href="index.php/for-the-authors/">For the authors</a><br/>
     <a id="mm_4" href="index.php/resources/">Resources</a><br/>
     <a id="mm_5" href="index.php/contact-promotion/">Contact<br/>& promotion</a><br/>
   </div>
   <div id="mm_tail"></div>
</div>
(...)
```

CSS:

```
div#mainMenu{
        float: left;                                                  
        width: 140px;
        height: 430px;
        margin-top: 48px;
        background-image: url("img/mainMenu.svg");
        background-size:cover;
        text-align: center;
}

div#mainMenu a{
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-size: 10.6pt;
        text-decoration: none;
}

div#mainMenu a:link, div#mainMenu a:visited, div#mainMenu a:active {
        color: #262E5B;
}

div#mainMenu a:hover{
        color: #262E5B;
}

a#mm_1 {
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        top: 21px;
        left: 18px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 35px; 
        vertical-align: middle;
}

a#mm_1:hover, a#mm_1:active {             <-- THIS IS NOT WORKING
        background-image: url('img/ElementAbout.png');   
        background-size: cover;
}

div#mm_links{
        clear:both;
        height: 430px;
}

div#mm_tail{
        background-color: white;
        border-left: 2px solid #262E5B;
        border-right: 2px solid #262E5B;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #262E5B;
        width: 30px;
        height: 100%;
        clear: both;
        float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish? If you remove the :hover and press the link I think you will find that the :active is working just fine. But it doesn't do much good since you are styling it the same as when you hover over it. So basically you are hovering over it and then the background-image shows, then you click the link and the same background-image keeps showing.

```
a#mm_1:active {        
        background-image: url('img/ElementAbout.png');   
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I would like to have highlighted link when user is on the page where it lead in the same way as he move mouse on it. Is it not the way `:active` should work?

Comment: No. :active means: do this while I click on the element.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`:hover`** pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) selects an element when the mouse cursor is right above it.

The [**`:active`** pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) applies styles when the element is clicked (or activated in another way).

In your code, your `:hover` and `:active` styles are identical.

```
a#mm_1:hover, a#mm_1:active {
        background-image: url('img/ElementAbout.png');   
        background-size: cover;
}
```

You won't notice any difference when hovering or clicking.

However, give each a different style and you'll see the difference:

```
a#mm_1:hover { background-color: yellow; }

a#mm_1:active { background-color: red; }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/heqkvnm5/)